# How to use a custom typescript interface in Pinia Store + Sidebase/nuxt-auth?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia, nuxt-auth

I'm working on a Vue/Nuxt 3 project using composition API. Therefore I'd like to use the composition api in my Pinia stores as well.

I'm trying to setup a Pinia store to store my user data that I get from my backend using the @sidebase/nuxt-auth package.

I made a Typescript interface that represents my user: User. This is the same as my response from /user, the endpoint that the nuxt-auth package uses to get my user data.

Currently I can't figure out how to do it without errors, or without doing: `const user = ref<any>(null)`

This is my current code for my store:

```
import { User } from '~/types/User.interface'

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
  const { signIn, data, token } = useAuth()
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()
  const user = ref<User>(null)
  const loading = ref<boolean>(false)

  async function loginUser(credentials: { emailAddress: string; password: string }) {
    loading.value = true
    try {
      await signIn(
        { email_address: credentials.emailAddress, password: credentials.password },
        { callbackUrl: '/shows' }
      )
      user.value = data.value
      loading.value = false
      return 200
    } catch (e: any) {
      loading.value = false
      return e.status
    }
  }
```

This is my user type:

```
export interface User {
  id: number
  email_address?: string
  phone_number?: string
  public_id: null
  account_type: string
  created_at: string
  updated_at: string
  last_login_at: string
  active: number
  locale: string
  selected_publisher_uuid?: string
  permissions: { [key: string]: boolean }
  should_see_changelog_modal: boolean
  two_factor_confirmed: boolean
  do_two_factor_challenge: boolean
}
```

The type I can find for Signin()

```
export type SignInFunc<PrimarySignInOptions, SignInResult> = (primaryOptions: PrimarySignInOptions, signInOptions?: SecondarySignInOptions, paramsOptions?: Record<string, string>) => Promise<SignInResult>;
```

This is the error I get:
`Type 'SessionData | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'User | undefined'.`

**How do I properly set the type of my user ref inside the Pinia store, and how do I set it to be the  api response that nuxt-auth receives from my backend?**

Comment: Don't use composition API in pinia stores. Compostion API is useful in components, because you can separate concerns. If you need to separate concerns in stores, you need a separate store. Please read [What syntax should I pick](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#what-syntax-should-i-pick) from pinia documentation.

Comment: Point here being: Options stores make you understand the basics of how a store functions. They give you a necessary foundation of what state, getters and actions are and how they are related. Once you're familiar with that, it will be easy to transition to Composition Stores, but without the Options stores step,  you're more likely to run into problems when using Composition Stores, which are perhaps a bit too fluid.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of how stores work. I've used Vuex before this. My question is about how to correctly type refs inside a Pinia setup store and how to work with refs that are not defined from the start.

Comment: The same way you'd do it in the setup function of any component, really. The problem here is not the store. It's `signIn` function which seems to be returning types which are not compatible with User's types. Also, you're not showing what each of those types mean (`User`, `SessionData`,...)